# How do I create a customized table with dynamic columns and rows with respect to API data in React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, datatable, react-table

I am trying to build a customized data table in react with API data and I don't want to hard code the header value, instead I want the header will be created with respect to API key and its value pair. Can anyone help me do that? Is that possible?

```
Right now am using React-table with hardcoded headers but it isn't solving my problems. Any help will be appreciated.
 Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.